# Copy SD Card contents to USB HDD

Tags: file-transfer, usb-host-mode

I'm considering to buy an Android Tablet (e.g. Nexus 7). One of the things
I would like to do is, copy some content of my SD Cards (e.g. camera, gopro) to
a USB HDD.

Can I do this with an android tablet? What app(s) do I need (if any)?
Anything else?

Is somebody aware of any instructions or How Tos that describe this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: The n7 doesn't support writing to USB drives out of the box, you need to [root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android_OS)) it + [StickMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount). More [here](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-use-your-usb-flash-drives-nexus-7-root). One can also install a custom firmware, eg CyanogenMod. Other brands may support this out of the box. Besides this limitation: The N7 is very capable an worth it's money, it's also rather easily moddable and will receive longer software support than others (just some hints on the pros/cons).

Comment: Thanks ce4! How about the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7". I have seen that it has a USB connectivity kit? would that also be a solution? THX!

Comment: The Samsung Tab would be possible, for sure. I prefer Google Nexus devices because of superior experience (longer software suppport cycle, faster updates, great community support for 3rd party firmware, etc.). They're also very cheap to boot. So: If you don't mind to root it and/or install a custom ROM like CyanogenMod, go for a Nexus 7. Else buy the Samsung tab (Here's a [side by side comparison](http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=5091&idPhone2=4543) of N7 and Tab2, note the LCD and processor/graphics differences especially)

Comment: Note that the Samsung has a micro SD slot that supports up to 32 GB. I have an N7 myself, but I'm looking at using it to backup photos to HDD. Whatever I end up doing, I need to factor in an external SD card reader.